# Change the look of the Tkinter scrollbar widget Python

Tags: python, tkinter, styles, scrollbar

I was wondering if there was a way to change the look of the Tkinter scroll bar? I have searched online but I could not find anything on what I was looking for. I would like to change it from the look it has to more of a scroll bar that you would see in Google Chrome. Any ideas? I just need a push in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

ttk styles are the way to go.
http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/styles.html

I use the plastik theme as a good reference, it is an image based theme.

You can then replace the images with your own.

to get the source and files:
http://svn.python.org/projects/sandbox/trunk/ttk-gsoc/samples/plastik_theme.py

I just ran the 2to3 conversion tool and works great in python3

Assuming you move all the images to a relative path called /img you can do

```
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import os
import plastik
plastik.install((os.getcwd()+'/img/plastik'))

scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

listbox = Listbox(root)
listbox.pack()

for i in range(100):
    listbox.insert(END, i)

listbox.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)
```

Note: You have to use the ttk.Scrollbar widget not the tkinter widget

Comment: Why are you recreating the scrollbar on the last line of code, whtout packing it? Also, Your final line of code is `scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)`. Aren't you missing `ttk.` in front of `Scrollbar` since you imported ttk as ttk?