# Python tkinter scale/scrollbar widget, putting image on it

Tags: python, tkinter

I cannot find any way to put custom images on the tkinter scale/scrollbar widget.

Is there any way to do it?

All I can do was changing background or highlightcolor or throughcolor.

But I want to change the slider image because it looks really bad.

Sorry for my bad English.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by *"I want to change the slider image"* as in you want to change the image associated with the bar which moves back and forth on the slider? Or the background in the slider's "rail"? Or the arrows on either side of the slider?

Comment: Both of it, the bar skin, and the background in the slider's rail (scrollable area). Also I wanna remove the arrows (in case of scrollbar).               
I want to apply custom skins on both bar and slider's rail.

Comment: This answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28375591/changing-the-appearance-of-a-scrollbar-in-tkinter-using-ttk-styles

Comment: am I allowed to put image on "style" ?