# Tkinter how to correctly style a combobox scrollbar

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I'm trying to style a combobox widget scrollbar. I would like to set the trough color and size.
I have been able set the size by changing the arrowsize parameter as in the code below. This is undesirable though because it changes all vertical scrollbars for all widgets. I would like to target specific widgets.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.title('Default Demo')
        self.geometry('420x200')

        style = ttk.Style()
        style.configure('my.TCombobox', arrowsize=30)
        style.configure('Vertical.TScrollbar', arrowsize=28)
        # style.configure('my.TCombobox.Vertical.TScrollbar', arrowsize=28)

        values = []
        for idx in range(1, 50):
            values.append(f'Testing-{idx}')

        cbo = ttk.Combobox(self, values=values, style='my.TCombobox')
        cbo.grid(ipady=5)


def main():
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: If you want different styles then you need to creat some. You can do more than one costum styled Scrollbar and add them to the widget you want. Maybe I miss the problem here.

Comment: You also need to take a look a this for your color <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28375591/changing-the-appearance-of-a-scrollbar-in-tkinter-using-ttk-styles>

Comment: @Atlas435, I'm trying to style the scrollbar in the combobox dropdown. I don't know how to address it. I tried the commented out code above but it did nothing.

Answer (score 2):

The combobox's scrollbar is not directly accessible through the python interface, but you can change its style through the tcl interpreter.

First, give a name to the combobox's dropdown:

```
self.tk.eval('set popdown [ttk::combobox::PopdownWindow %s]' % cbo)
```

Then change the style of the scrollbar:

```
self.tk.eval(f'$popdown.f.sb configure -style my.TCombobox.Vertical.TScrollbar')
```

Full example:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.title('Default Demo')
        self.geometry('420x200')

        style = ttk.Style()
        style.configure('my.TCombobox', arrowsize=30)
        style.configure('my.TCombobox.Vertical.TScrollbar', arrowsize=28)

        values = []
        for idx in range(1, 50):
            values.append(f'Testing-{idx}')

        cbo = ttk.Combobox(self, values=values, style='my.TCombobox')
        cbo.grid(ipady=5)

        self.tk.eval('set popdown [ttk::combobox::PopdownWindow %s]' % cbo)
        self.tk.eval(f'$popdown.f.sb configure -style my.TCombobox.Vertical.TScrollbar')

        ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical').grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```