# Python: "Tuple" is not defined warning

Tags: python, pylance

I'm writing a function that returns a tuple and using type annotations. To do so, I've written:

```
def foo(bar) -> Tuple[int, int]:
    pass
```

This runs, but I've been getting a warning that says:

> "Tuple" is not defined Pylance report [UndefinedVariable](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/blob/main/DIAGNOSTIC_SEVERITY_RULES.md#diagnostic-severity-rules)

Given that I'm writing a number of functions that return a tuple type, I'd like to get rid of the warning. I'm assuming I just need to import the package `Tuple` refers to, but what is the right Python package for it?

From my research, I'm inclined to think it's the `typing` package, but I'm not sure.

Comment: `(int, int)` is a value, not a type.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Depending on your exact python version there might be subtle differences here, but what's bound to work is

```py
from typing import Tuple

def foo(bar) -> Tuple[int, int]:
  pass
```

Alternatively I think since 3.9 or 3.10 you can just outright say `tuple[int, int]` without importing anything.

Comment: Thanks, I've implemented the second solution, although as written, it initially gave a `Subscript for class "tuple" will generate runtime exception; enclose type annotation in quotes`.

Comment: This worked with `def foo(bar) -> "tuple[int, int]":`